# how to prove that localisation preserves Hom's

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Can anyone tell me where I can read a proof that the natural map

$Hom_{A}(M,N)[S^{-1}]\rightarrow Hom_{A[S^{-1}]}(M[S^{-1}],N[S^{-1}])$

is an isomorphism if $M$ is finitely presented?

Comment: This is a) an easy exercise, b) standard material, for example included in Bourbaki's book on commutative algebra. In any case it is not appropriate for mathoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can read a proof of this fact at:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75812/does-localisation-commute-with-hom-for-finitely-generated-modules

Comment: @Ramsey: When easy question are answered, other questions of this type will occur again.

Comment: I was kind of hoping that the terse reference to MSE would be taken as a bit of a hint that this question would be better asked there.

Comment: Ramsey:  I see what you were thinking (and can imagine thinking the same way myself), but I suspect this sort of subtlety is likely to be lost on anybody who is too intellectually lazy to do his own homework.

Comment: Steven, that's pretty harsh. This could be a research mathematician who is asking a question outside his/her field, and not necessarily an "intellectually lazy" student. The OP might not have realized that it's regarded as an easy question. 